# retrieve some text from url string and save to a separate string

Tags: java, android, string, url

I have the following url and i want to retrieve the part 124301. this number is different every time. how can i get it and save it to an other string

```
 String pageurl = "http://www.examplewebsite.com/article/124301/blabalala/blalalalaa"
```

Comment: i have not tried something......i thought to try to split it but i don't if it's possible .it's not an array

Comment: Always give things a try before you ask - you learn so much more by trial and error than by having the answers given to you. Failure is a valuable experience {:v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `http://www.examplewebsite.com/article/` part is fixed, so you can get that simply this way:

```
String pageurl2 = pageurl.replace("http://www.examplewebsite.com/article/", "");
String result = (pageurl2.split("/"))[0];
```

also there you can use regular expressions too.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested, but something like this should work:

```
 String pageurl = "http://www.examplewebsite.com/article/124301/blabalala/blalalalaa"
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\/article\\/(\\d+)\\/");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pageurl);

    if(matcher.find()){

        return matcher.group(1);

    } else {

        return null; //not found

    }
```

Comment: The pattern can be simplified to `"article/([\\d]+)/"`